# Python убрать то что уже было

Tags: python

Есть 2 строки, к примеру

```
one = "Привет. Как ты?"
two = "Привет. Как ты? Я хорошо"
```

как сделать что бы убрать все слова которые были в первой из второй
что ыб получилось

```
two = " Я хорошо"
```

Comment: Все слова по отдельности или фразу целиком? Почему перед буквой `Я` должен остаться пробел?

Comment: без разницы как убрать главное что бы убрало,пробел тоже не принцепиален

Comment: `two[len(one):]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```
one = "Привет. Как ты?"
two = "Привет. Как ты? Я хорошо".replace(one, '').strip()
print(two)
```

))
А если перед "Я" пробел, то strip() не надо. Можно сделать еще проверку, есть ли содержимое one в two:

```
one = "Привет. Как ты?"
two = "Привет. Как ты? Я хорошо"

if one in two:
    two = "Привет. Как ты? Я хорошо".replace(one, '').strip()

print(two)
```

Вариантов масса.

Comment: спасибо большое